# How to convert a byte array into a string in CAPL?

Tags: capl, canoe, canalyzer

I have a byte array and I need to print the elements in a single line.

I tried using '`snprintf()`' but it won't take a byte array as its input parameter.

I tried copying the byte array into an integer array and then used the `snprintf()`, but instead of printing the HEX values, corresponding ASCII values are printed.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: variables
{
  byte response[100];
  int i,ar[100];
  char out[100];
}

on diagResponse TCCM.*
{
  s1=DiagGetPrimitiveData(this,response, elcount(response));
  for(i=0;i<s1;i++)
  {
     ar[i]= response[i];
     out[i] =response[i];
  }
   snprintf(out,elcount(out),"%X",out);
   write("HEX Response : %s",out);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
variables
{ 
  int ar[100];
}

on diagResponse TCCM.*
{
  char tmp[8];    // Temporary buffer containing single HEX value
  char out[301];  // Bigger output string and "local" to function
  // Better to place them there (i and response) if they are not global
  int i;
  byte response[100];
  
  out[0] = 0;     // Clear output string
  
  s1 = DiagGetPrimitiveData(this, response, elcount(response));

  for (i = 0; i < s1; i++)
  { 
    ar[i] = response[i];
    snprintf(tmp, elcount(tmp), "%.2X ", response[i]);  // byte to HEX convert
    strncat(out, tmp, elcount(out));  // Concatenate HEX value to output string
  }

  write("HEX Response : %s", out);
}
```

Olivier

Comment: It worked.......Thanks a lot. I was stuck there for some days.